# Plot a map using wheel encoder and IMU data

Tags: mobile-robot, slam, wheeled-robot, python, mapping

I want to plot a map( with matplotlib or any other library ) using a wheel encoder and IMU data.

Eg:- For every 10cm robot moves it should draw line (in a graph) and draw angles depending on the data received from the IMU.

I'm using python in Raspberry pi.

How can I achieve this function? Is there any algorithm for this? I googled for a couple of hours but still found nothing.

Comment: I think you didn't check enough, it is pretty easy at least the first steps. What you should check out are 1) forward kinematics (for wheeled robots) to get position from encoder measurement and 2) sensor fusion in order to use also the data from IMU.

Comment: Thanks.Forward kinematics didn't come in mind as they are mostly used in robotic arm manipulation. I will research on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe look at SLAM. Sinultaneous Localization and Mapping. There are really robust ROS packages which might help you in doing it. However, usially SLAM uses cameras, LIDARs, kinect-like sensors. But you could try if you can find some sort of implementation with IMU and Encoder.

For example I found [this](https://youtu.be/aXeNBHmOaEE) Or [this](https://youtu.be/nQZeAafDEJE)

I hope this might be useful for you.